# How to use Textile in PHP?

Tags: php, textile

a (hopefully) quick question - how can I use Textile in PHP? As in, I have some textile-formatted text that I want to convert to html using php. If I was using Ruby I'd use RedCloth but I can't seem to find a similar solution for php.

Anybody any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get, for example, [the original Textile library](http://textile.thresholdstate.com/).

Comment: Ahh ok... I was about to ask how to use it but there's an example file included that shows you how to use it in PHP... :-) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To be more specific, what the Example file has is:

```
// A simple example

require_once('classTextile.php');

$textile = new Textile();

$in = <<<EOF

A *simple* example.

EOF;


echo $textile->TextileThis($in);

// For untrusted user input, use TextileRestricted instead:
// echo $textile->TextileRestricted($in);
```

And for those whom Heredoc string syntax might be confusing (Like myself) here is the basic form.

```
require_once('classTextile.php');

$textile = new Textile();

echo $textile->TextileThis('A *simple* example.');
```